# Aspose Table of Contents Won't Update Fields (C#)

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I have created a Table of Contents (TOC) with dynamic content. Most of the rows follow predefined styles, these are applied correctly.

There is an option in Aspose to deviate from these styles if you wish. The issue I stumbled on is that when generating the document with Aspose, it seems `document.UpdateFields();` does not properly update the rows that are styled by other means than the predefined ones.

Once the document is generated (the styling is correctly applied on the page) I can right click the TOC and click update entire field. After that the styling shows up. Has anyone encountered this issue and has a fix/workaround/solution?

Comment: Please share your input Word document here for testing. I will investigate the issue and provide you with more information on it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.